# É possível adicionar connection string dentro de uma classe?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho um projeto do tipo **class library** onde tenho o meu Contexto, nela eu pego a conexão SQL que está no meu **`web.config`**.

Como eu poderia adicionar a conexão SQL de forma que fique dentro da DLL? Quero passar a conexão direta aqui, sem precisar usar o web.config:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString
```

Tenho isso:

```
public Contexto()
{
    minhaConexao = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString);
    minhaConexao.Open();
}
```

Comment: Você quer remover o uso de **`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString`**. Isso?

Comment: sim, quero adicionar conexão dentro da classe para não ficar visível no web.config

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar uma string para inserir a conexão.. isso não seria uma boa por que para mudar a conexão você teria que recompilar a dll.

```
 minhaConexao = new SqlConnection("Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;UserId=myUsername;Password=myPassword;");
```

> **Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
>   Password=myPassword;**

Comment: Agradeço! eu prefiro recompilar que deixar aberto, questão de segurança mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode passar a conexão diretamente como parâmetro de **`SqlConnection`**, afinal o retorno de **`ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"]`** é uma simples string. Isso não me parece uma boa ideia, mas sem mais detalhes não tem como saber.

Se você tem completa certeza que a string de conexão não vai mudar, não vejo problemas em fazer assim.

```
private const string StringConexao = @"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=NomeBanco;Integrated Security=True"

public Contexto()
{
    minhaConexao = new SqlConnection(StringConexao);
    minhaConexao.Open();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Quando você usa:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString
```

Está utilizando a configuração do projeto ativo, ou seja, o arquivo `.config` ligado ao aplicativo que está sendo executado.

Assim sendo, além de ser uma má prática distribuir uma DLL com um arquivo `.config`, a ideia não vai funcionar, porque este arquivo jamais será lido.

Agora, se você quer usar a configuração do arquivo `Web.config` do projeto que usa a DLL, você terá que fazer uma lógica um pouco mais espertinha. Algo como:

```
public Contexto()
{
    String connectionString = "Sua connection string default aqui";
    if (ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"] != null)
    {
        connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conexao"].ConnectionString;
    }

    minhaConexao = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    minhaConexao.Open();
}
```